# Принцип подстановки Лисков и предусловия

Tags: .net, архитектура, наследование, полиморфизм

Принцип подстановки Лисков прямо подразумевает, что предусловия не должны усиливаться в подклассах. Это логично (потому что переопределённый метод подкласса, для которого входные данные окажутся неприемлимыми, будет работать некорректно/выбросит эксепшн). Но как тогда спроектировать следующую архитектуру:

Есть класс скажем Vehicle (можно его сделать абстрактным, не суть важно), у него есть виртуальный метод Weight (пусть этот метод делает какие-то заумные вычисления для каждого типа транспортного средства в зависимости от массы, не столь важно):

```
public abstract class Vehicle
{
    public virtual void Weight(int w)
    {

    }
}
```

Теперь у нас есть класс Motorcycle, который мы наследуем от Vehicle, но мы должны ограничить его макс массу скажем в 200 кг.

```
public class Motorcycle : Vehicle
{
    public override void Weight(int w)
    {
        if (w > 200)
            throw new WeightOverflowException();
    }
}
```

вроде всё прекрасно, логичное наследование, с наследованием всех свойств и поведения, но нарушает же LSP:

```
        List<Vehicle> list2 = new List<ConsoleApp1.Vehicle>();
        list2.Add(new Motorcycle());

        foreach (var item in list2)
        {
            item.Weight(400);
        }
```

полетит же эксепшн WeightOverflowException, о котором базовый класс не должен вообще ничего знать.
Как правильно спроектировать такую задачу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В проектировании по контракту существует понятие "доступности предусловия". Это означает, что клиентский код должен иметь возможность узнать, а удовлетворяет ли он предусловия или нет.

Тут можно сказать, что поскольку в предусловии участвует аргумент, который клиент и передает, то это правило соблюдается. Но само предусловие меняется в зависимости от типа и не является явным.

В этом случае мы можем выделить предусловие в отдельный метод и сделать само предусловие полиморфным:

```
public abstract class Vehicle
{
    public virtual bool IsWeightValid(int w) {return true;}
    public virtual void Weight(int w)
    {
       Contract.Requires(IsWeightValid(w));
    }
}
```

Теперь, мы говорим нашим клиентам: "прежде чем дергать метод `Weight` убедитесь самостоятельно, что аргумент валиден". Да, это может выглядеть перебором. И я бы прибегал к этому трюку в крайнем случае, чтобы не усложнять API. Но это довольно распространенный паттерн. Например, коллекции в BCL выставляют свойство `IsReadOnly`, которое (теоретически) должно быть проверено перед вызовом метода `Add`.

Кто-то считает поведение из BCL нарушением LSP, но я так не думаю: метод имеет право выражать свои предусловия в более абстрактном виде, через свои собственные свойства или методы. `Contract.Requires(ImInValidState)` ничем не хуже (теоретически), чем `Contract.Requires(methodArgument != null)`.

Comment: Ну это фактически второй подход из моего ответа: ослабить условие на метод базового класса.

Comment: Сори, я писал ответ до того, как увидел твой.
Но ведь здесь условие не ослабляется: оно остается столь же строгим, как и изначально. Его поведение просто становится полиморфным. ИМХО, это не одно и тоже.

Comment: Когда все что угодно может бросить исключение и у клиента нет возможности понять, когда это происходит, является ли это исключением нарушением предусловия/постусловия/инварианта, то это просто отсутствие DBD.
З.Ы. Для этого нужно не ослабить предусловие, а усилить. Т.е. базовый метод должен всегда бросать исключение. Тогда это будет соответствовать принципу подстановки.

Comment: Ну, наличие отдельного метода для проверки в принципе тоже возможный вариант, хотя теоретически не отличается от исключения (ну да, вызов нужно окружать блоком try/catch): просто проверка валидности входных аргументов производится по-разному. (Кстати, проверка валидности не всегда возможна, пример: `File.Open`.)

Comment: Не вполне понимаю, почему для корректности базовый метод должен _всегда_ бросать исключение. По-моему, достаточно, чтобы он _не гарантировал_ отсутствие исключения.

Comment: Отсутствие прпедусловия в базовом классе, равносильно Contract.Requires(true). Если наследник начинает что-то требовать (например, аргумент должен быть в определенном диапазоне), то он требует больше. Это нарушение LSP. Если предусловие в базовом методе Contract.Require(false), т.е. метод никогда нельзя использовать. То наследник со своей валидацией аргументов уже ослабляет предусловие. А это допустимо.

Comment: По поводу File.Open - тут нужно отличать предусловия от постусловий. Предусловием File.Open является валидность пути. Отсутствие файла - не является предусловием. Все остальное - системные ошибки, которые контрактами ну никак не покрываются.

Comment: Я здесь веду речь не о контрактах. Почему бы не написать в документации на метод: любое значение входного параметра может быть, а может и не быть ошибочным? Это, разумеется, разрешает имплементацию `Contract.Require(false)`, но хотя бы не отпугивает юзера. Хотя, думаю, мы говорим об одном и том же.

Comment: т.е. мы в базовом классе закладываем всю сопутствующую инфраструктуру, включая все специфические эксепшины и т.д.?

Comment: @OlegSh по сути да. Выбрасываемое исключение - это же часть контракта. Обычно мы определяем в базовом классе, что метод может бросать SomeBaseExpception, а наследники могут бросать его или более специальный тип исключения.

Answer (score 0):

Подход, который мне нравится — иммутабельность.

При этом ваш вес будет устанавливаться в конструкторе, и там же будет проверяться. Соответственно вы просто не сможете создать объект с неправильной массой.

Мутирующий метод `Weight` (который по идее правильнее назвать `SetWeight`, правильно?) при этом не нужен.

---

Другой подход, при котором масса таки остаётся мутабельной — объявить, что установка массы *всегда имеет право бросить исключение*, даже для базового объекта. Мне такой подход нравится меньше, но он тоже имеет право на жизнь.

Comment: "Мутирующий метод Weight (который по идее правильнее назвать SetWeight, правильно?) при этом не нужен." - я же специально обозначил, что этот метод делает что-то "полезное", иначе достаточно было бы свойства :)

Comment: Т.е. в базовом классе устанавливаем макс. массу и там же проверяем (можно ещё в виртуальном методе Weight() базового же класса описать предусловие, что масса не должна быть более заявленной максимальной)? А если масса вообще будет не нужна (например, будут использоваться другие методы) - то значит, что-то не так с SRP ?

Comment: @OlegSh: Если масса вообще не нужна, то непонятно, почему данный объект есть потомок исходного.

Comment: @OlegSh: Для конкретно вашего примера, масса транспортного средства — штука неизменная, разве нет? Так что устанавливающий её метод по идее не нужен. Если не так, расскажите подробнее вашу модель.

Comment: например, для одних потомков имеет значение, для других нет. Хорошо, пусть этот метод называется по-другому, как Вам нравится, просто в нём используется масса.

Comment: @OlegSh: Раз не для всякого потомка имеет значение, значит, она не должна присутствовать в базовом объекте. По-моему, так.

Comment: тогда мы приходим к тому, с чего начали - ужесточение предусловий в дочернем классе со всеми вытекающими последствиями

Comment: @OlegSh: Ну да. Но если у нас дочерний объект — это разновидность базового, значит, базовый объект не может гарантировать больше, чем дочерний. Логично.

Comment: Так дочерний начинает ужесточать предусловие, а это нарушение LSP же

Comment: @OlegSh: Подождите, предусловие в LSP имеется в виду то, которое имеет уже созданный объект. Во время создания объекта проблем нет. Или о каких конкретно условиях мы говорим сейчас?

Comment: причём тут создан уже объект или нет. Я не хочу проверять Weight в конструкторе, потому как не факт, что эта масса потребуется (правда я не уверен, что в этом случае не нарушается SRP). Да и вообще, мне не нравится это "распыление", проверка значения в одном месте, а использование в другом.

Comment: @OlegSh: Вы невнимательно прочитали то, что я пишу. Ещё раз: если некоторым потомкам нужна масса, а некоторым не нужна, значит **в базовом объекте не должно быть массы**.

Comment: масса нужна в вычислениях, но не везде есть её лимит